# Convert BYTE* to Array<byte>^

Tags: c++-cx

Is it possible to convert byte* to Array^ in C++/CX?

Currently I accomplish this by copying each value, which I know is **not** space/performance efficient.

My current implementation is :

```
Array<byte>^ arr = ref new Array<byte>(byteCount);
for (int i = 0; i < byteCount; i++)
{
    arr[i] = *(bytes + i);
}
```

Comment: Use ArrayReference<> instead.

Comment: @HansPassant [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/jj127099) says "By using ArrayReference to fill a C-style array, you avoid the extra copy operation that would be involved in copying first to a Platform::Array variable, and then into the C-style array". So I guess ArrayReference is used for copying to a C style array when my use case is to copy from a C style array to Platform::Array class.

Comment: Do note that passing an Array across the ABI will incur a copy anyway. To avoid copies, use IBuffer (although avoiding the copy may be a little tricky if one of the parties is .NET.. it's certainly possible).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's an array constructor for that ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/hh441578)):
`Array(T* data, unsigned int size);`

So in your case, simply do:
`Array<byte>^ arr = ref new Array<byte>(bytes, byteCount);`

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/hh700131) is a great article on C++/CX and WinRT array patterns.

Answer (score 1):

If you care about performance use [`Platform::ArrayReference`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj127099.aspx) instead [`Platform::Array`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh441539.aspx)

And if you will need `Platform::Array` you can just cast like this

```
uint8_t *data;
size_t data_size;
...

auto arrayRef = new ArrayReference<uint8_t>(data, data_size);
Array^ array = reinterpret_cast<Array<uint8_t>^>(arrayRef)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can also use

```
Array<byte>^ t = ref new Platform::Array<byte>(byteReaded);
CopyMemory(t->Data, buff, byteReaded);
```

for copy or for access using

```
t->Data
```